# One point compactification of the cotangent bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles

For concreteness I want to work with $\mathbb P^1$. We know already that its cotangent bundle is $\mathcal O(-2)$, and the canonical compactification is the space $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal O(-2) \oplus \mathcal O)$. I've read the posts [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1380512/compactifying-mathcalo-mathbbp1-2) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2042207/how-to-understand-the-projective-compactification-of-a-vector-bundle), although my algebraic geometry is not good enough to understand them entirely.

I want to understand how those posts relate to the one point compactification of $T^*\mathbb P^1$.
The way I'm currently visualising it is that $\mathbb P^1$ is the sphere, $T^* \mathbb P^1$ is the sphere with a bunch of complex planes arranged to vary algebraically across the surface (their duals technically, but in dimension 1 I'm not missing anything by considering $\mathbb C^*$ as $\mathbb C$), and so $T^* \mathbb P^1$ is the same bundle but with all these complex planes compactified to the same point.
In essence, it looks like a sphere ($\mathbb P^1$) covered by a bunch of spheres (which look like $\mathbb P^1$) all glued/pulled to a point at infinity (each of the cotangent spaces at the points on $\mathbb P^1$).

It's not fully clear to me how this relates to $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal O(-2) \oplus \mathcal O)$.
In some sense, $\mathcal O(-2) \oplus \mathcal O$ is just $\mathbb P^1$ with a space that looks like $\mathbb{C}^2$ at each point instead of $\mathbb{C}$.
Then the projectification is just compactifying each of these $\mathbb{C}^2$, i.e. making $\mathbb{P}^1$, and doing so 'compatibly'.

My questions are: is the construction I outlined above 'the same' process as projectifying $\mathcal O(-2) \oplus \mathcal O$, and if so, why? Is there some 'deeper' reason/philosophy behind why they're the same process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the one-point compactification of $T^*\Bbb P^1$ is very different from taking $\Bbb P(\mathcal{O}\oplus\mathcal{O}(-2))$. The latter is a $\Bbb P^1$ bundle over $\Bbb P^1$, while the former cannot be a fiber bundle over $\Bbb P^1$: where would you map your one added point to? One-point compactifications are not often considered in algebraic geometry - they're more of a tool of topology.

Comment: While it is true that in AG we rarely consider the one-point compactification, in this particular case we at least have the contraction of the $(-2)$-curve on $\mathbb P(\mathcal O \oplus \mathcal O(-2))$ whose image is the quadric cone; I'm not positive, but it seems plausible to me that the quadric cone is at least homeomorphic to the one-point compactification of $T^* \mathbb P^1$. All that's just to say that while these two are different objects, they are not completely unrelated.

Comment: (+1) Re: Tabes Bridges' suspicion, the one-point compactification of the total space of the _tangent_ bundle is the blow-down of the $-2$ curve (at infinity) in the stated ruled surface. The one-point compactification of the _cotangent_ bundle is topologically the result of collapsing a curve of self-intersection $+2$, e.g., the zero section of the _tangent_ bundle $\mathcal{O}(2)$.

Comment: Thank you both for the discussion.